# Write java to execute curl command line

Tags: java, curl

I want to write java code to implement this curl command:

```
 curl --form "file=@7_018011.gif" --form "apikey=helloworld" --form   
 "language=por" https://api.ocr.space/Parse/Image >> m.txt
```

where **@7_018011.gif** is the name of the image i want user to input to send the request to a RESTFUL service. Where can i start ?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can i start ?

Start by reading the javadocs for `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`.  Read the linked (duplicate) Q&A as well.

However, note that the `>> m.txt` is shell syntax, and you can't pass that as an argument if you run `curl` directly.  In other words, some of the solutions to the linked Q&A are not directly applicable.

There are two alternatives:

1. Run via a subshell; e.g. run this command:

   ```
     sh -c 'curl --form "file=@7_018011.gif" 
                 --form "apikey=helloworld" 
                 --form "language=por" 
                 https://api.ocr.space/Parse/Image >> m.txt'
   ```
2. Implement code to write the output to "m.txt" in Java.